# how to delete an entire row if checked in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table with 5 columns. the first column has a check box, when checked I can either edit or delete the entire checked row. Im using react hooks to do that. now I can edit the entire row but I can't delete the row. here is my code.

```
  const handleCheckbox = id => {
    console.log("called");
    const checkedRow = [...users];
    checkedRow[id].select = !checkedRow[id].select;
    setUsers(checkedRow);
    setNewCheck([...checksArray, checkedRow]);

    // id = newCheck.length + 1;
    // setNewCheck([...newCheck, id]);
    console.log("checkArray", checksArray);
  };
```

> > in the previous code I can pass the row id to the checkbox method then I want to add the the rows ids to the array to delete them.

```
const initialFormState = {
    id: null,
    code: "",
    englishName: "",
    arabicName: "",
    remarks: "",
    checkedGroup: []
  };

  // Setting state
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(usersData);
  const [checksArray, setNewCheck] = useState(initialFormState.checkedGroup);
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
```

> > the previous code belongs to the array and the values in the array.

How can I delete the entire row? am I approaching this the right way or is there a better way to do it? thanks in advance.

Comment: check out `useDispatch` https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RamyM.Mousa  thanks, but i want to build it using react hooks only without redux any ideas?

Comment: `checksArray` and `users` are linked add checked property to a user in `users` array. It will be easier than keeping those two arrays in sync.